# Firebase Deploy - Flutter web - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSupported' of undefined / Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope

Tags: firebase, flutter

My Flutter web app provides 2 error messages after deploying to firebase. The error messages were not appearing prior deployment. I can not find the root cause.

```
main.dart.js:39105 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSupported' of undefined
    at aaA.a2R (main.dart.js:47197)
    at Object.aP_ (main.dart.js:22954)
    at main.dart.js:10007
    at aGN.a (main.dart.js:5110)
    at aGN.$2 (main.dart.js:38004)
    at Object.H (main.dart.js:5096)
    at aHW (main.dart.js:10032)
    at main.dart.js:97159
    at main.dart.js:97153
    at dartProgram (main.dart.js:97156)
(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://*****.web.app/') with script ('https://*****.web.app/flutter_service_worker.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

The app is functioning when run under web render without any issue.

My guess comes from the firebase JavaScript files does provide error message with stored in Firebase.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="***">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="*/*** Store">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="234259997949-29sp95o3qnl5s9ofdl0ib2eb7mho1avm.apps.googleusercontent.com">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>Eletanco Store</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first --> 
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  
<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
****
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>

<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>

  <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-remote-config.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-performance.js"></script>
  <!-- 
    initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded, set useEmulator to false
    to avoid connecting the SDK to running emulators.
  -->
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

1. I removed the following

   if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
          window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
          });
        }

   I upgraded all the javascript links and launched again Firebase Initiates.

Comment: Any explanation why would this work ? What are the implications of removing this ?